# Trying to understand Tasks in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Ok I've been messing around with tasks in .net 4.5 and I'm trying to get my head around everything so I created a small app that does some work and I have a few questions about it.

Here is the code:

Account Controller.cs:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager _manager;

        public AccountController()
        {
            _manager = new UserManager(ContextFactory.GetContext());
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await _manager.FindAsync(model.UserName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            //do some work
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot Find User");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

User Manager.cs:

```
 namespace MvcApplication1
 {
   public class UserManager
   {
     private readonly IDBContext _context;

     public UserManager(IDBContext context)
     {
       _context = context;
     }
     public Task<UserProfile> FindAsync(string ID)
     {
       var queryHelper = new UserQueries(_context);
       var localID = ID;

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => queryHelper.GetProfile(localID));
      }
   }
 }
```

UserQueries.cs:

```
public class UserQueries
{
    private readonly IDBContext _context;
    public UserQueries(IDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public UserProfile GetProfile(string ID){
        DataTable dt = _context.ExecuteDataTable(...)
        //do work with dt and return UserProfile
    }
  }
}
```

IDBContext.cs

```
public interface IDBContext
{
    DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters);
}
```

So I have a few questions here.

Do I have to create a new instance of the UserQuery class in every function? Not sure if it needs to be sync locked or not, still confused there.

Do I need to copy the ID to localID, I'm worried about scoping and reference changes when the function is called, is that even something to worry about in any case?

Should UserQueries be `Task<UserProfile>` as well?

If UserQueries should be `Task<UserProfile>` should the DBContext that returns a DataTable also be `Task<DataTable>`, does .net have a function for Taskable sql calls?

I'm not 100% sure how deep you go with Task

Comment: "*does .net have a function for Taskable sql calls*" it depends, what are you using to make your SQL calls? Entity Framework, ADO.NET, Linq2Sql, 3rd party? Many of them have async method calls but it depends on which you use.

Comment: new SqlConnection("Connection String") class

Comment: That would be `ADO.NET`, and yes. look at all the functions that end in `Async` like [`OpenAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh223688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh204867%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

unless `ExecuteDataTable` has a Async version built in I would recommend against using Tasks. If you have to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` to make it work, you should likely not be doing it and you will get worse performance under load than you have gotten just leaving it synchronous.

`Task.Run` (and `Task.Factory.StartNew`) **should only be used when you are waiting on a task that is CPU bound**. `ExecuteDataTable` is a I/O operation, you are waiting for the database to respond, whatever API you are using to talk to the database may expose functions that return `Task` and those you could await on (and you would need to `await` all the way up your chain of calls to the first call) but if it does not expose a function that returns a `Task` you should just do it the normal way.

Comment: So you should only use Tasks when you know the lowest function is going to be CPU bound or if a Library exposes an Async function? Other than that just leave it sync?

Comment: Correct, that would be the general rule of thumb. (assuming that the library was written correctly and they did ***not*** do "fake async" like you where trying to do by wrapping a sync function in a `Task.Run`)

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Is there a rule of thumb on when something is CPU bound? I'm guessing this would come up when you start thinking you could use threads in an instance just use tasks instead.

Comment: Task's are wrappers, they could be [a thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they could be [a event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or they could be a [async callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321469%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The point of Tasks is you used to write three different styles of code to handle those 3 types of async code, Tasks let you handle all 3 types with one code style. When working with ASP.net you should avoid thread tasks but embrace the other two to help scaling

Comment: Ok so the last question I have was about the UserQueries instance in the functions and the local Copy of the variables. Do I have to worry about those questions?

Comment: No, the reason you have to do that is for `foreach` loops and capturing variables incorrectly. Look in to the term "variable capture" to learn more.

Comment: It depends on if `IDBContext` is thread safe or not and if requests use the same instance of `UserManager` or separate ones. If `UserManager` gets resued for multiple concurrent requests and `IDBContext` is not thread safe then you will need to either lock or just make and dispose the `IDBContext` per request instead of caching it.

Comment: +1. I'd actually go a bit stronger and say that in general `Task.Run` should only be used to invoke CPU-bound code from the UI thread. It really has (almost) no place at all in an ASP.NET application (where any CPU-bound code should just be executed directly on the request thread).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok that makes perfect sense I think I'm starting to really understand all this task stuff.